# async-http-client requests timing out with NettyAsyncHttpProvider

Tags: java, netty, threadpoolexecutor, asynchttpclient

I'm using `async-http-client` but I'm having trouble with `NettyAsyncHttpProvider`.

It gives this warning:

```
Oct 28, 2014 12:50:16 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorkerPool
WARNING: Failed to get all worker threads ready within 10 second(s). Make sure to specify the executor which has more threads than the requested workerCount. If unsure, use Executors.newCachedThreadPool().
```

My problem here is even if I use a `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` the following issue will persist.

Once the number of threads reaches the `corePoolSize`, requests get dropped. 
Whatever `requestTimeoutInMs` or other options I try, only a fraction of the responses come back and the threads in the pool stall.

```
ExecutorService executor = new CustomThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2, 60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), new ThreadFactory() {
        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            int number = threadCreationCount.incrementAndGet();
            LOG.info("newThread - {} ", number);

            Thread th = new Thread(r);
            th.setName("AsyncHttpClient-" + number);
            LOG.info("thread ={}", th);
            return th;
        }
    });

    AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder builder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder();
    builder.setMaximumConnectionsTotal(-1)
            .setMaximumConnectionsPerHost(-1)
            .setConnectionTimeoutInMs(1000)
            .setIdleConnectionInPoolTimeoutInMs(60000)
            .setIdleConnectionTimeoutInMs(60000)
            .setRequestTimeoutInMs(3000)
            .setFollowRedirects(true)
            .setMaximumNumberOfRedirects(5)
            .setAllowPoolingConnection(true)
            .setIOThreadMultiplier(4)
            .build();

    builder.setExecutorService(executor);

    AsyncHttpClientConfig config = builder.build();
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(new NettyAsyncHttpProvider(config), config);

    //Spin up 500 async requests to google.com
    for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
        LOG.info("i = {}", i);
        ListenableFuture<Response> future = client.prepareGet("http://www.google.com").execute(
                new AsyncCompletionHandler<Response>() {
                    @Override public Response onCompleted(Response response) throws Exception {
                        LOG.info("Response = {}, count = {}", response.getStatusCode(),
                                responseCount.incrementAndGet());
                        return response;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onThrowable(Throwable t) {
                        LOG.error("on throwable ={}", t);
                    }

                });
    }
```

Now If I change from `NettyAsyncHttpProvider` to `ApacheAsyncHttpProvider` all the requests are performed.

I created a sample project on github to showcase the issue. [async-http-client-debugging](https://github.com/tinnou/async-http-client-debugging.git)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue when using the default executor service. I didn't debug into why, but using this configuration below, I didn't get the 10 second delay and warning message.

```
AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder builder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder();
    builder.setConnectTimeout(3000)
            .setExecutorService(new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 20,
                    60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    new SynchronousQueue<>()))
            .setRequestTimeout(3000)
            .setReadTimeout(3000)
            .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

That's not a threading issue. There's 2 things in play here:

- you're sending a huge bunch of requests at the same time, without any back pressure, so you're trying to open 500 concurrent connections at the same time. You'd better have a queue and a dedicated Executor in front of AHC so you can limit and control the number of concurrent flying requests.
- you're hammering google.com. They don't let you do that of course, and block your connect attempts.

PS: You would have get a faster answer if you would have asked on the AHC google group instead.